# Alternative way to handle controller action authorization instead of using customattribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-web-api2

i have webapi action which is decorated with customauthattribute for authorization.  This attribute internally checks with db if current user has viewcustomer permissions.   Does anyone know better way of handling it instead of using customattribute.   may be intercepting somewhere all request and run authorization checks for user/permisson/resource he is trying to access : eg getcustomer for customer id 10. So if user doesnt have access  see customer id 10 he should get 403 status.

```
[CheckPermission(Process.CustomerManagment,Permissions.View)]
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer(int customerId)
{
}
```

Comment: You could add a global filter but that means the code is completely separate from your action methods so can be a bit confusing.

Comment: is there any other way instead of using attributes or global attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add global filters in the configuration of your web api.

Practically in your startup class (startup.cs or webapi.config) you can call on the httpconfiguration object the following method

```
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Filters.Add(new MyAuthFilterAttribute());
```

In this way it will be global for all your api calls.

You should extend the IAuthenticationFilter interface.

take a look here for documentation
[webapi documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a filter that you can apply globally. For example, something like this. Yes it's horrible but gives you a start:

```
public class GlobalAuthoriseAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute  
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        switch (controllerName)
        {
            case "Home":
                //All call to home controller are allowed
                return;
            case "Admin":
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can add this to your entire app in the `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs` file:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new GlobalAuthoriseAttribute());
}
```